# Weight of MLP is larger than 1

Tags: neural-networks, weights, perceptron

I noticed when training MLP that weights of neurons can be larger than 1. Would this have negative effects on the outcome of the network? If yes, how to mitigate this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Of course they can be larger than $1$, since MLP does not enforce any hard constraint on its weights. In general, negative effects are produced when weights become very large, not when larger than specifically $1$. To mitigate such issues, you can apply regularization or increase its degree if you're already using it.

If you use the MLP implementation in `scikit-learn`, the regularization is achieved by `alpha` parameter. Typically, it's set to some value other than $0$, so you probably have some degree of regularization in your model. This parameter increases/decreases the level of `L2 regularization` you apply to the weights, which means punishing square of $W_{ij}$ severely for it not to become too large.